# How do read a NLTK grammar from inside a GZIP file?

Tags: python, nltk

How do you load a compressed grammar file into NLTK? I can load an uncompressed grammar file just fine, with:

```
import nltk
parser = nltk.load_parser('grammar.fcfg')
```

but since my grammar file is nearly 100MB, I want to load the much smaller compressed version, which is only 1MB, but this fails with:

```
import nltk
parser = nltk.load_parser('grammar.tar.gz')

ValueError: Could not determine format for file:///grammar.tar.gz based on its file extension; use the "format" argument to specify the format explicitly.
```

Unfortunately, looking at `nltk.data.FORMATS` doesn't list any compressed formats.

Comment: RTFM the [`zlib` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html).

Comment: Or the [`tarfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html), which supports unpacking gzipped archives directly.

Comment: If this is UNIX, FIFOs can be used to pipe output from the unpacker without using disk space. Or a file at `tmpfs` if you have enough memory.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by examining [the source of `load_parser`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/util.py#L22), it [relies](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/data.py#L926) on [`ntlk.data.find`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/data.py#L550) to open `file:///` URLs.

That function autodetects GZipped data [by checking if the path ends with `.gz`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/data.py#L613) and [reads it](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/data.py#L406) with [`gzip.GZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html?highlight=gzip#gzip.GzipFile).

**But, for this to work, the data should be packed with `gzip` directly, not through `tar` or anything.**